# Want to change date format & timezone for DocuSign account

Tags: timezone, date-format, docusignapi

Is there any **DocuSign REST API** available to change date format and time zone information for DocuSign account ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be an administrator of the account you want to change:

1. Login to the DocuSign account in question.
2. Click the Profile drop-down in the top right.
3. Select **Go To Admin**.
4. Select **Regional Settings** on left hand side.
5. Modify your date settings.