# Prompt for Access Code each time a recipient access document

Tags: docusignapi

Our DocuSign users are accessing documents by clicking on a link in an email. We are specifying an Access Code on each recipient. But we want to prompt access code each time when recipient open document. There is settings available for the same but we do not want to change that account settings manually to login in to DocuSign web console. **But we want to manage this settings from DocuSign REST API. Is there any REST API available to so we can manage below account settings.**

1. Login to the **DocuSign web console** (as an Administrator).
2. Navigate to **Preferences >> Features**.
3. In the Drop-down List labeled Authenticate on return access to
   envelope, select the value **"Each Access"**.
4. Click the Save button

Comment: Why don't you want to change the account settings through the account settings screen? If you have different use cases where some people need the setting and others don't, you can establish multiple accounts within your organization for different sets of people. We have many customers who do this.

Comment: actually we want to allow our users to directly manage linked DocuSign account from our settings screen

Comment: also we want to allow our users to manage date format & time zone settings of there DocuSign account from our screen. Please visit : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761417/want-to-change-date-format-timezone-for-docusign-account

Comment: @larryK it would be good if you can help me.. thanks

Comment: @LarryK FYI : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037891/docusign-account-settings-invalid-value-specified-for-parameter-authenticatio

Comment: fyi answer provided on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037891/docusign-account-settings-invalid-value-specified-for-parameter-authenticatio

Comment: i already tried with same it was not working.. please see comment on same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found API is available to update this settings. Here are the details.

PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/settings

Set value of parameter "authenticationCheck" to "each_access" or "initial_access" as below.

```
{
  "accountSettings": [
    {
      "name": "authenticationCheck",
      "value": "each_access"
    }
  ]
}
```

OR

```
{
  "accountSettings": [
    {
      "name": "authenticationCheck",
      "value": "initial_access"
    }
  ]
}
```