# DocuSign account settings : invalid value specified for parameter: authenticationCheck

Tags: docusignapi

When we are updating DocuSign account settings using below REST API method its giving below error.

**PUT /v2/accounts/{accountId}/settings**

**Payload**
{"accountSettings":[{"name":"authenticationCheck","value":"each_access"}]}

**Result**
{
    "errorCode": "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER",
    "message": "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Invalid   value specified for parameter: **authenticationCheck**"
}

As per this error **"authenticationCheck"** is invalid parameter. But it is valid parameter because same parameter we are getting while retrieving of account settings using below REST API method.

**GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/settings**

**Result**
{"accountSettings": [{"name": "authenticationCheck","value": "inital_access"}]}

Can anyone help us how can we update this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PUT is correct, you just need to modify your JSON:

```
{
  "accountSettings": [
    {
      "name": "authenticationCheck",
      "value": "each_access"
    }
  ]
}
```

or

```
{
  "accountSettings": [
    {
      "name": "authenticationCheck",
      "value": "initial_access"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: no it is not working even on : https://apiexplorer.docusign.com/#/?categories=Accounts&tags=Accounts&operations=updateSettings

Comment: Fyi i tried using the api explorer, i received a success/green bar at the bottom of the page. Try refreshing the page and starting over in the API explorer. If there are any more details of the error you can share send over. Also, for additional troubleshooting you may want to enable logging on the DS side, so you can see exactly what your request looks like when it hits DocuSign: https://support.docusign.com/articles/API-Request-Logging

Comment: Thanks.. it got started work. i did not change anything in request. it was same as i tried before.. now its working.. once again thanks for the help..